# How can I link these two object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, imagemap

I have some areas of an imagemap and some checkboxes. Each area has a corresponding checkbox, how can I make it so when an area is clicked the corresponding checkbox gets ticked?

**Imagemap:**

```
  <%= image_tag("maps/mainmap.png", :width => "450", :height => "450", :class => "map", :usemap => "#mainmap", :alt => "") %>

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area id="area-42" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >

    <area id="area-43" shape="poly" 
      coords="296,103,258,133,254,143,252,166,242,203,263,209,272,204,322,226,340,250,360,241,356,230,357,222,378,214,395,195,394,188" alt=""
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >    
  </map>
```

**Checkboxes:**

```
<fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
  <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
    <p class="area_check"><%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
    <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label></p>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

**This produces this:**

```
  <img alt="" class="map" height="450" src="/assets/maps/mainmap.png" usemap="#mainmap" width="450" />

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area id="area-41" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >

    <area id="area-42" shape="poly" 
      coords="296,103,258,133,254,143,252,166,242,203,263,209,272,204,322,226,340,250,360,241,356,230,357,222,378,214,395,195,394,188" alt=""
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >    
  </map>

  <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <p class="area_check"><input id="area-41" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="41" />
      <label for="area-41"><p1>Chinatown</p1></label></p>
      <p class="area_check"><input id="area-42" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="42" />
      <label for="area-48"><p1>Village</p1></label></p>
  </fieldset>
```

I thought this bit of javascript might link the two, but it's not working, any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

```
  $(function() {
    $('area').click(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr('id');
      var $checkbox = $('[id=' + id + ']');
      $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    });       
  });
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Can you check if click is happening by placing an alert statement in the javascript function

Comment: Try debugging the javascript to see what happens inside the click function (or if it's being called at all). If you're using Firefox, try firebug. Chrome and Safari both have debuggers built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same id value in the `<area>` tags and in the checkboxes.  That will never work.  You also had several errors in how you were getting the `$checkbox` variable.

I changed the `<area>` tags to use a data value and changed the code to retrieve that data value and it works now.  You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ndwjC/.

Since we don't have the actual image, one has to guess where to click to find the hotspots, but when you find one, it toggles a checkbox.

HTML:

```
  <img alt="" class="map" height="450" src="/assets/maps/mainmap.png" usemap="#mainmap" width="450" />

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area data-areanum="area-41" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >

    <area data-areanum="area-42" shape="poly" 
      coords="296,103,258,133,254,143,252,166,242,203,263,209,272,204,322,226,340,250,360,241,356,230,357,222,378,214,395,195,394,188" alt=""
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >    
  </map>

  <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <p class="area_check"><input id="area-41" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="41" />
      <label for="area-41"><p1>Chinatown</p1></label></p>
      <p class="area_check"><input id="area-42" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="42" />
      <label for="area-48"><p1>Village</p1></label></p>
  </fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function() {
    $('area').click(function(){
      var name = $(this).data("areanum");
      var $checkbox = $('#' + name);
      $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    });       
  });
```

P.S.  If you're using a recent version of jQuery, you should probably use `.prop()` to change the checkbox rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Been stuck on this for far too long, this works a treat, thanks again!